# Direct access to image file provided cloud front

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

There is application which uses `cloudfront`

There are generated jpg files in source code.

So, I try to access jpg directly from browser like this

`https://dy43ylo5qsfd8.cloudfront.net/_pics/mypic/nice.jpg`

or from command line

`curl https://dy43ylo5qsfd8.cloudfront.net/_pics/mypic/nice.jpg`

However it shows error like this below.

```
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Request blocked. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: -TEpAe4gXZ7SOZM7Nb4VsCSZABiPvDyKFmq4354Bnx4aFo4q155Eng==
```

Is there anyway to make it possible to access the jpg directly??

Comment: What makes you think that they are valid URLs?

Comment: I open the source code of page. And this page shows `jpg` correctly

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page where it works correctly?